# Why does the gradient of matrix product $AB$ w.r.t. $A$ equal $B^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

The below passage is from p. 215 of [Deep Learning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org) by Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville.

> For example, we might use a matrix multiplication operation to create
>   a variable $C = AB$. Suppose that the gradient of a scalar $z$ with
>   respect to $C$ is given by $G$. The matrix multiplication operation is
>   responsible for defining two back-propagation rules, one for each of
>   its input arguments. If we call the bprop method to request the
>   gradient with respect to $A$ given that the gradient on the output is
>   $G$ , then the bprop method of the matrix multiplication operation
>   must state that the gradient with respect to A is given by $GB^T$.

They are applying chain rule to compute the gradient of scalar $z = f(C)$ with respect to $A$.  I am unfamiliar with the idea of computing the gradient of a product of matrices with respect to a matrix.  What does this mean, and why is the result transposed?

Comment: Doesn't it follow from the formula (6.47) on page 2007 and algorithms 6.2 and 6.4 on pages 209 and 213 respectively?

Answer (score 5):

Given the gradient wrt $C$ 
$$\eqalign{\frac{\partial z}{\partial C} = G\cr\cr}$$
use the [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product) to write the differential
$$\eqalign{
dz &= G:dC \cr
   &= G:dA\,B \cr
   &= GB^T:dA \cr\cr
}$$
From which the gradient wrt $A$ can be identified as
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial z}{\partial A} &= GB^T \cr\cr
}$$
Note that Frobenius products can be re-arranged in various ways
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= BC:A \cr
     &= A^T:(BC)^T \cr
     &= AC^T:B \cr
     &= B^TA:C \cr
     &= {\rm tr}\big(A^TBC\big) \cr
}$$
all of which can be verified directly, or by considering the trace-equivalence and the cyclic property of trace.

Comment: It appears that you are treating $d(C) = d(AB)$ as $d(A)B$.  How are you able to do this?  Isn't $d(AB) = (dA)B + A(dB)$?

Comment: @tmakino You are right.  But for this particular problem, $B$ is constant and $A$ is variable.  So $dB$ is equal to zero, leaving only the $dA$-term.

Comment: The Frobenius Inner Product link is broken. The correct link is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product .

Comment: A few questions: 1) Did you just take the inner product of both sides with $dC$? 2) Why the switch to $d$ instead of $\partial $?

Comment: @hans Can you explain *why* the differential can be written as the Frobenius inner product of G and dC? In particular, according to the wikipedia page on matrix calculus, it seems that the dimension of the dAB/dA should be n^2 by n^2 (if A, B are both square matrices of n). You're saying it's n by n.

Comment: @hans Where could I find a ressource explaining how dz/dC = G is equals to dz = G : dC ?

Comment: @user3243135, It makes sense that if you want to have the total variation on $z$, you must multiply each small variation of $C$ (i.e. $[dC]_{ij}$) by the gradient in that direction (i.e. $G_{ij}$), and add them all up : $\sum_{i,j}G_{ij}[dC]_{ij}$ and that is the Frobenius inner product $G : dC$, which is written $tr(G^TdC)$.

If you are dealing with vectors, the equivalent would be the scalar product $a^Tb$ : e.g. $dz = <g,dc> = g^Tdc$

Answer (score 1):

I disagree, unless $A$ is an $1 \times m$ matrix. Let us assume $A$ is an $1 \times m$ matrix and $B$ is a $m \times n$ matrix. The product is $y=AB$ is a $1 \times $n matrix. We can write
\begin{eqnarray}
  y_i = \sum_{k=1}^m a_k b_{ki}.
\end{eqnarray}
Then the gradient is given by the partial derivatives
\begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{\partial y_i}{\partial a_j} = \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{\partial a_k}{\partial a_j} b_{ki} = \sum_{k=1}^m \delta_{kj} b_{ki}
= b_{ji} 
\end{eqnarray}
which in matrix form is $B^T$.

However, if $A$ is an $p  \times m$ matrix things are different.
The gradient of $y=AB$ with respect to $A$ is a fourth order tensor.
Let us do the math.
\begin{eqnarray}
   y_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^m a_{ik} b_{kj}
\end{eqnarray}
and from here
\begin{eqnarray}
   \frac{\partial y_{ij}}{\partial x_{rs}} = \sum_{k=1}^m 
    \frac{\partial a_{ik}}{\partial a_{rs}}  b_{kj}
      = \sum_{k=1}^m \delta_{ir} \delta_{ks} b_{kj}
      = \delta_{ir} b_{sj}
\end{eqnarray}
A four rank tensor which is a tensor product of delta and 
the matrix B.

Comment: You don't "disagree". Your calculation actually _confirms_ what the text says. Observe
$$\eqalign{
h_{rs} &= \frac{\partial z}{\partial a_{rs}} 
  =\frac{\partial z}{\partial y_{ij}} \; \frac{\partial y_{ij}}{\partial a_{rs}} 
  = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y_{ij}} \; \delta_{ir}  b_{sj} \\
&= \frac{\partial z}{\partial y_{rj}} \; b_{sj} 
  = g_{rj}\,b_{sj} 
  = g_{rj}\,b^T_{js} \\
}$$
Or in matrix notation: $\;H=GB^T$