# What is the gradient of a reduction operation on a Matrix?

Tags: matrices, vector-analysis, machine-learning

Let's say that at some point we obtain a matrix A:
[
 [2, 4],
 [6, 8]
]
And we do a sum on the axis 1, we will obtain a vector B:
[
 [6],
 [14]
]
If the gradient w.r.t B is:
[
 [7],
 [2]
]
Then the gradient w.r.t A is:
[
 [7, 7],
 [2, 2]
]
I don't understand why we replicate the gradient on the reduced dimension and why for instance we don't split the gradient like:
[
 [3.5, 3.5],
 [1, 1]
].
If someone as a mathematical explanation or a link to some resources it would be helpful.

My question comes from the following comment in the TensorFlow source code:

// The partial derivative for any input along a "reduced" dimension

// is just 1, so we only need replicate the output gradient on such a

// dimension to its "expanded" shape.

// Running example:

// input is

// [[a, b, c],

//  [d, e, f]]

// reduction_indices = [1]

// Sum = [a + b + c, d + e + f]

// if the gradient is [g1, g2]

// We want the propagated gradient to be

// [[g1, g1, g1],

//  [g2, g2, g2]]

I initially asked the question on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/6zho5z/d_what_is_the_gradient_of_a_reduction_operation/) but the answers don't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have been given a scalar function of the vector $b$ and its gradient, i.e. 
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= \phi(b),\,\,&g= \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial b} \cr
}$$
Let's assume we are subsequently told that $b$ is actually a function of a matrix $A$, specifically $$b=A\,1\,\implies\,\,db=d\!A\,1$$ 
where $1$ is a vector with all elements equal to one.

We can find the gradient wrt $A$ by way of the differential
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= g:db \cr
   &= g:d\!A\,1 \cr
   &= g1^T:d\!A \cr
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial A} &= g1^T \cr
}$$ where a colon is used to represent the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
So the replication, as you call it, is due to the presence of the $1^T$ term.

Comment: That's exactly the same kind of answer as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846339/why-does-the-gradient-of-matrix-product-ab-w-r-t-a-equal-bt. Even if I know calculus I don't know how to use the Frobenius Inner Product to write the differential. Do you know a resource that I could read ?