# How to calculate the gradient of $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^2(\mathbf{W}^2)^T\mathbf{x}$ w.r.t. $\mathbf{W}$?

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, gradient-flows

I need to calculate the gradient of $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^2(\mathbf{W}^2)^T\mathbf{x}$ w.r.t. $\mathbf{W}$. Here is what I have tried. Let $A=W^2$, then the form reduces to
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{AA}^T\mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{A}} 
=&\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{B}^T} \quad\quad (\text{where }\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}^T) \\
=&\left(\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{B}}\right)^T \\
=&\left(\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T+\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T)\right)^T\\
=&2\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{B}^T\\
=&2\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}
\end{align*}
which follows from the formula (77) in Matrix Cookbook, specifically,
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\mathbf{c}}{\partial\mathbf{X}}=\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{b}\mathbf{c}^T+\mathbf{c}\mathbf{b}^T).
$$
I was trying to use the chain rule since we already know
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^2(\mathbf{W}^2)^T\mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{W}^2}=2\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^2.
$$
The next step is supposed to be
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^2(\mathbf{W}^2)^T\mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{W}}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{W}^2}{\partial\mathbf{W}}\frac{\partial x^T\mathbf{W}^2(\mathbf{W}^2)^Tx}{\partial \mathbf{W}^2}
$$
where we use the denominator layout. However, the dimension of
$
\frac{\partial\mathbf{W}^2}{\partial\mathbf{W}}
$
does not fit the dimension of $\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^2(\mathbf{W}^2)^T\mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{W}^2}$, namely $2\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^2$. Does anyone give me any clues? I appreciate it.

Update: I tried to use Frobenius inner product to do it as follows. Let $z=\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^2(\mathbf{W}^2)^T\mathbf{x}$, then we have
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}z&=2\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}:\mathrm{d}\mathbf{A} \\
&=2\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}:\mathrm{d}\mathbf{W}^2\\
&=2\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}:(\mathrm{d}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}+\mathbf{W}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{W})\\
&=2\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}:\mathrm{d}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}+2\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}:\mathbf{W}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{W}\\
&=2\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{W}^T:\mathrm{d}\mathbf{W}+2\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}:\mathrm{d}\mathbf{W}\\
&=2(\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{W}^T+\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}):\mathrm{d}\mathbf{W}
\end{align*}
which gives the solution
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^2(\mathbf{W}^2)^T\mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{W}}=2(\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{W}^T+\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}).
$$
I tested this result with a $2\times 2$ $\mathbf{W}$ using the auto-differentiation tool by PyTorch which gives an identical result. This implies that the above derivations are correct.

Comment: This question has been solved in the update part by myself. I closely follow this useful link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846339/why-does-the-gradient-of-matrix-product-ab-w-r-t-a-equal-bt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$\mathbf{y}=(\mathbf{W}^2)^T \mathbf{x}$.
It holds
\begin{eqnarray*}
d\phi 
&=& 2 \mathbf{y}:d\mathbf{y} \\
&=& 2 \mathbf{y}\mathbf{x}^T:d(\mathbf{W}^2)^T  \\
&=& 2 \mathbf{B}:d(\mathbf{W}^2)  \\
&=& 2 
\left[\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{B}+
\mathbf{B} \mathbf{W}^T \right]
:d\mathbf{W}
\end{eqnarray*}
where
$\mathbf{B}
=\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^T
=\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{W}^2$.
The LHS term is the gradient you found by yourself.